# React scroll to top on page refresh - don't restore position

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently trying to scroll to top on page refresh. So far I've been able to implement scroll to top on route change, but not **on page refresh - somehow react always restores its previous position**. How can I prevent that from happening?

That's how I implemented scroll to top (thought `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` inside of `componenDidMount()` would help, but it didn't):

```
class ScrollToTop extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        if (this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return null;
    }
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

```
class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <ScrollToTop/>
                <Header/>
                <Home/>
                <Projects/>

                <div className="follow-cursor"/>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: On page refresh, whole application is restarted. So all your states goes back to their default values. If this functionality is really important to be done even after the refresh, then store scroll position in your local storage or else use a BE request to store.

Comment: @Nayanshah I want the scroll position to not be restored. I want it to scroll to the top on refresh, currently it isn't.

Comment: "somehow react always restores its previous position." This is incorrect, react does not store any state for scroll, especially on page refresh. Maybe some thing in your app is affecting the position.

Comment: @HassaanTauqir That's weird, my app barely even contains code yet.

Comment: I have the same behaviour. When I refresh, the page is reloaded in the previous position. Weird!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT**

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72478740/5421321) is a better approach for this problem since its using react `hooks` instead of pure-js all over the place.

**ORIGINAL**

You can use some pure JS for that:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

This will make page scroll to top before it reloads, so everything will be fine when reload ends.

Answer (score 6):

Try this solution inside of App.js. It worked for me.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    window.history.scrollRestoration = 'manual'
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way of implementing a Custom Component for Scroll To Top in React-17.0.2 is by using hooks:

Step 1: Create custom component:
**ScrollToTop.js**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router";

const ScrollToTop = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!location.hash) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  }, [location]);

  return <>{props.children}</>
};

export default ScrollToTop;
```

Step 2: Call ScrollToTop component into Root:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Router>
          <ScrollToTop />
    <Switch> ..... </Switch>
            </Router>
      </BrowserRouter>

    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I feel like this should be the accepted solution, namely the accept js solution can be an anti-pattern.